# jQuery. Function to find first div containing invalid fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, findfirst

I have a form divided into three tabs and validate it with jQuery validation plugin. User can switch between tabs with links. After submit button is pushed and validation failed, error class is being added to links which corresponding tabs/containers has errors. This made with next function:

```
function treatFormLinks () {
    $('.formTab').each(function(){
        $("#" + this.id + "Link").toggleClass('hasErrors', !$('input, select, textarea', this).valid());
    });     
};
$("#Submit").click(function () {
    $('.FormNavi a').removeClass('hasErrors');
    treatFormLinks();
});
```

Here's html example, just to explain the idea how it works:

```
<a href="#" id="OneLink">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="OneLink">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="OneLink">Link 3</a>

<form>
    <div class="formTab" id="One">... form fields ...</div>
    <div class="formTab" id="Two">... form fields ...</div>
    <div class="formTab" id="Three">... form fields ...</div>
</form>
```

What I need is to find **first** div, which contains invalid fields and the show this one. Let's say `#One` and `#Three` divs' fields are valid and div `#Three` is visible. What I want is to show `#Two` after pushing submit button.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the div right after you set the link.

```
function treatFormLinks () {
    var alreadydisplayed = false;
    $('.formTab').each(function(){
        $("#" + this.id + "Link").toggleClass('hasErrors', !$('input, select, textarea', this).valid());
        alreadydisplayed?void(0):$(this).css("display","");//if an invalid tab has already been displayed, do nothing
        alreadydisplayed = true;
    });     
}
```

Comment: This actually works, but I jump to the very first, instead of first *invalid* tab.

Answer (score 0):

I extended the function with next:

```
$("#" + this.id).toggleClass('tabHasErrors', !$('input, select, textarea', this).valid());
$(".formTab").hide();
$(".formTab.tabHasErrors:first").show();
```

Not too elegant but works.